# Error when trying to deploy SharePoint 2010 solution package - SharePoint 2010 - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-deployment

After several deployments, I receive the following error when trying to re-deploy a solution:

> Error occurred in deployment step
>   ‘Recycle IIS Application Pool’: The
>   communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext,
>   cannot be used for communication
>   because it has been Aborted.

The only solution I have found (not ideal) is to restart Visual Studio.

Anyone know a better way?

Comment: I prefer WSPBuilder for packaging and deploying solutions.

Comment: Sometimes the only solution is to restart Visual Studio ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen this a couple of times as well and the only resolution I found was to restart Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

How come restarting Visual Studio will fix anything :)

You need to run Visual Studio as Administrator (by right clicking on its icon)

If still persists, restart the server.

If still persists, add the administrator account under which you are running Visual Studio to Sharepoint Central Administration for that sharepoint web portal.